# A question about performance in sql script

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about performance in a script. I have a stored procedure like this:

```
procedure my_procedure (IN document_number_parameter varchar(100))
begin
select a.id,
       b.code
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on a.b_id = b.id
where case when document_number_parameter is null then 1=1
      else b.document_number = document_number_parameter
end;
```

Actually, table b has an index in the column document_number.
What is better? this script or create a dynamic query using the document_number_parameter and adding in script the 'where' statement by demand?, I wonder if the database use full scan or index scan when *document_number_parameter* is not null.

Well, I've added a limit clause but is not relevant in this case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a dynamic query. Just put the condition in the procedure rather than the query.

```
IF document_number_parameter IS NULL
THEN
    select a.id,
           b.code
    from table_a a
    inner join table_b b on a.b_id = b.id;
ELSE 
    select a.id,
           b.code
    from table_a a
    inner join table_b b on a.b_id = b.id
    WHERE b.document_number = document_number_parameter
END IF;
```

Comment: Well, the question is about how the database works, if use ```case when document_number_parameter is null then 1=1
      else b.document_number = document_number_parameter```, does the database use full scan or index scan?

I thought your option but I couldn't prove if the using case option is better than your option. Perhaps, it's the same, but I don't know.

Comment: We'd have to see the result of `EXPLAIN` to be sure.

Comment: But my intuition is that it will do a full scan because it doesn't realize that the case expression is the same for all rows, so it can transform it into my code automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.